# WordPress connection lost between roles and capabilities

Tags: wordpress

I have the following issue in the WordPress:
When I connect with the administrator account, the page *mysite.com/wp-admin/* gives the error message:

*You do not have sufficient permissions to access this admin page.
Reason: The current user doesn't have the "read" capability that is required to access the "Dashboard" menu item.*

But when I go, as I am still logged, to the page *mysite.com*, I can see the administrator bar on the top of the screen.

So there is still some link between the user and its administration role but I am not able to access any page in */wp-admin/*.

I already tried to add new user with admin rights directly in the database (wp_users & wp_usermeta tables) but without success.
I also tried to disable all plugins via FTP but no success neither.

Any ideas please? Thank you!

Comment: Did you recently change the prefix of tables in the database? This can occur during migration as well.

Comment: No, I didn't change the prefixes. And I checked in the database, it looks fine. IN the wp_capabilities in the wp_usermeta, the value is "a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}". I already tried all the "fix proposals" that I found on the internet but without success. I replaced the value in the wp_user_roles in the WP_options table by the wordpress default value... And still the same issue.